# How to share common functionalites across two angular apps

Tags: angularjs

In my one project i have two apps. lets say PurchaseApp and SalesApp.  These two apps are using a shared service (or factory)  called  Resourcesvc.js.  Currently the structure of two
apps are given below

**PurchaseApp.js**

```
var PurchaseApp= angular.module('PurchaseApp', []);
PurchaseApp.factory("Resourcesvc", ["$http", "$q", Resourcesvc]); // Registering Resource DI in app
PurchaseApp.controller("organizationCtrl", ["$scope", "organizationFactory",organizationCtrl]);
```

**SalesApp.js**

```
    var SalesApp= angular.module('SalesApp', []);
    SalesApp.factory("Resourcesvc", ["$http", "$q", Resourcesvc]); / Registering Resource DI in app
    SalesApp.controller("organizationCtrl", ["$scope", "organizationFactory",organizationCtrl]);
```

Its working fine now . but is there any better approach or practice available to share common service across module /Apps  . ( Really i am confusing angular app vs module)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make one module for each app and one module for your shared services then

```
var serviceModule= angular.module('ServiceModule', []);
serviceModule.factory("Resourcesvc", ["$http", "$q", Resourcesvc]);

var purchaseModule= angular.module('PurchaseModule', ['ServiceModule']);
purchaseModule.controller("organizationCtrl", ["$scope", "organizationFactory",organizationCtrl]);

var salesModule= angular.module('SalesModule', ['ServiceModule']);
salesModule.controller("organizationCtrl", ["$scope", "organizationFactory",organizationCtrl]);
```

Now your service is only declared once, in a `ServiceModule` and you have two other "apps" (really `modules` as you identified in your question) that each declares a dependency on it. `Resourcesvc` can now be injected into any controller/service in both modules.

Declaring dependencies on other modules (both your own and 3rd party ones) are what the `[]` part of a module declaration is for.